# Empty referrer in YouTube API requests

Tags: http, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrieve a channel's video list from the YouTube API. Actually, this functionality is already implemented, but suddenly stopped working.

Here's what I have:

- A GET request to the **search** endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`;
- Some query params:

  1. `part=snippet,id`
  2. `channelId=UCSJ4gkVC6NrvII8umztf0Ow` (just an example)
  3. `maxResults=5`
  4. `order=date`
  5. `key=[MY_API_KEY]`

I guess everything's alright, but for some reason I get this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer <empty> are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from referer <empty> are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I really don't know what's wrong, and every request returns the same error.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks for the attention!